# mongodb community installed but no mongodb folder

Tags: mongodb, windows-10, 64-bit

I'm trying to install mongodb community server, the msi file downloads and I go through the wizard with no problems, but when I finished, I couldn't find a folder titled "MongoDB" or anything like that in Program Files or Program files (x86). Cans someone help? Are there any prerequisites? Because I didn't download any.

Using windows 10 64 bit

Comment: You get an error?

Comment: I got no error.

Comment: @otherwall Have you restarted your pc after installing?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted it.

Comment: I have absolutely the same problem. I'd be willing to bet this is due to the fact that in order to modify "Program Files" you need to give admin privileges but neither the installation asks you to do that nor does it offer the option to "Run as Administrator". I even tried installing using the unattended method but noting seems to happen once I clicked "enter".

Comment: Also, Neil Lunn, I'm not sure why this was marked as a duplicate to a completely unrelated question. This is not a question of "How do I install mongodDB". This is a question of "Why the heck isn't the installation working".

Comment: Ok so because this got closed by someone who didn't bother to actually read and comprehend the question I'll drop the answer in here for the benefit of anyone facing the same issue. In short, the current .msi installation for version 3.6.4 is broken on windows 10. Once you go to the community edition download page, you'll see an "All version binaries" button that takes you to a page with all mongodb binaries. I got the 3.4-latest .msi installer and that worked on my machine. Hope this helps someone else with the same issue.

Comment: Well, I didn't realize they have .zip's that are not installations. So you can just download the .zip of version 3.6.4 (latest as of now) and be done with it. Apparently it's just a case of bad win .msi installer.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has to be installed somewhere but if you're looking for config files they are not created automatically (AFAIK), unlike on any Linux distro. I don't use Windows too often but if you can't use the search tool, you may want to start wizard again until you reach the point where you see a path under which MongoDB is installed by default, right?

But if you need a config, you need to follow official [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#set-up-the-mongodb-environment) guide. Create a basic config and see if it works. If you don't know what YAML is, read about that. Then, if you want to create a real config file that fits your needs, read about other options over [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

Comment: I know where mongoDB is installed by default I followed every guide and tutorial I could find, and nothing happened. There's no option to set a file path or config, its just an msi file, nothing else at all.

Comment: Please download manually.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Please check this out 
https://medium.com/@PrathapGunasekara/introduction-to-nosql-and-configure-mongodb-4-0-in-windows-1cb03ff59499?source=your_stories_page---------------------------